# ROR accepts_nested_attributes_for one to many relationship with selection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

I have two models Doctors and Questions like the follwong:

Doctor Model

```
class Doctor < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :questions
has_many :brands
accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions
end
```

Question model

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :discipline  
belongs_to :doctor
belongs_to :brand
end
```

Now you can clearly see that Doctor has many questions and brands and question belongs to doctor and brand.I want to add previously saved question to a doctor from doctors edit page.
I want to remove them as well.How can I proceed ?

I tried like :

```
<%= form.fields_for :questions, question,:child_index => (question.new_record? ? "index_to_replace_with_js" : nil) do |question_form| %>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="label">Select Question</div>
        <%= question_form.collection_select :id, Question.all, :id, :title ,{:include_blank => true } %>
      </td>          
    </tr>
  </table>
```

but this doesnot works for me.Can you give me a solution with proper example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It semes like
http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1 and
http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

answer this well.

Comment: I had already looked at this. please look at the line "I want to add previously saved question to a doctor from doctors edit page". how can i do that?Specifically this is my question.